# Why returned value is not being saved in DetailsView?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, detailsview, databound

The null object reference was solved. Now I need the returned value to be saved to the record. Here is the data bound code:

```
Private Sub dvSMasterCurrentYear_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles dvSMasterCurrentYear.DataBound
        Dim dv As DetailsView = New DetailsView
        dv = dvSMasterCurrentYear
        If DetailsViewMode.Insert Then
            Dim ctl = dv.FindControl("PlantYear")
            If ctl IsNot Nothing Then
                DirectCast(dv.FindControl("PlantYear"), TextBox).Text = GetYear()
            Else
                Throw New Exception("Control was not found")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here is the `GetYear` function:

```
 Public Function GetYear()
        Dim thisDate As Date = Now
        Dim thisYear As String
        'thisDate = #2/12/1969#
        thisYear = Year(thisDate)
        Return thisYear
    End Function
```

For inserting I use this :

```
 Private Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserting(sender As Object, e As DetailsViewInsertEventArgs) Handles dvSMasterCurrentYear.ItemInserting
            Dim view As DetailsView = DirectCast(sender, DetailsView)
            Dim txtYearPlant As TextBox = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, DetailsView).FindControl("PlantYear"), TextBox)
End Sub
```

This is what the mark up looks like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year Plant (yyyy)*">
                      <ItemTemplate>
                         <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlantYear") %>'></asp:Label>
                          <%# Eval("Year")%>
                     </ItemTemplate>  
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="PlantYear" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="PlantYear" runat="server" Text='<%# GetYear()%>'></asp:TextBox >
                     </InsertItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>
```

Markup looks like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year Plant (yyyy)*"> 
   <ItemTemplate> 
       <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlantYear")%>'></asp:Label> 
       <%# Eval("Year")%> 
   </ItemTemplate> 
   <EditItemTemplate> 
      <asp:TextBox ID="PlantYear" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>      
   </EditItemTemplate> 
   <InsertItemTemplate> 
      <asp:TextBox ID="PlantYear" runat="server" Text='<%# GetYear()%>'></asp:TextBox > 
   </InsertItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I don't know why the value is not being saved, so how do I fix it?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Markup looks like:  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Year Plant (yyyy)*">
                      <ItemTemplate> <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PlantYear")%>'></asp:Label> <%# Eval("Year")%>
 </ItemTemplate>  <EditItemTemplate> <asp:TextBox ID="PlantYear" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                     </EditItemTemplate>
                     <InsertItemTemplate>
                          <asp:TextBox ID="PlantYear" runat="server" Text='<%# GetYear()%>'></asp:TextBox >
                     </InsertItemTemplate>
                 </asp:TemplateField>

Answer (score 0):

In  Private Sub DetailsView1_ItemInserting event I changed

Dim txtYearPlant As TextBox = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, DetailsView).FindControl("YearPlant"), TextBox)

TO

Dim txtYearPlant As TextBox = TryCast(view.FindControl("YearPlant"), TextBox)
 e.Values.Add("YearPlant", txtYearPlant.Text)

So now the value in the PlantYear textbox is saved to the record.